# coloring in ggplot2 for US map

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot2 in R

I want to assign colors to the 48 contiguous states based on their rankings, which range from -2 to 2. States with negative rankings will be colored red, while those with positive rankings will be colored green. States with a ranking of 0 will be given a white color. The intensity of the color will represent how close a state's ranking is to either -2 or 2.

I used the following code

```
install.packages("usmap")
install.packages("ggplot2")

library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)

# Sample state rankings
state_rankings <- data.frame(state = c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT",
                                       "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN",
                                       "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA",
                                       "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV",
                                       "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH",
                                       "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN",
                                       "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"),
                             ranking = runif(50, min = -2, max = 2))

# Get state polygons
state_map <- us_map(regions = "states")

# Merge state polygons with ranking data
state_map_rankings <- merge(state_map, state_rankings, by.x = "abbr", by.y = "state")

# Create the ggplot2 map
ggplot(state_map_rankings, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, fill = ranking)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = "green", midpoint = 0) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

However, the states don't look right and there are many missing gaps in the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to show the colours, then I think you can use the built-in plotting function `usmap::plot_usmap()` which will work. Also I'd recommend using a smaller dataframe for ease if you can. Since each state has one value, the `statepop` dataframe should work.

```
statepop <- dplyr::left_join(
  usmap::statepop,
  state_rankings,
  by = c("abbr" = "state")
)

usmap::plot_usmap(data = statepop, regions = "states",
                  values = "ranking", color = "black") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(name = "Ranking", low = "red", mid = "white", 
                       high = "green") + 
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

gives this:

[image]

And if as you said you want to only plot the lower 48, you can add AK and HI to the `exclude` argument:

```
usmap::plot_usmap(data = statepop, regions = "states", exclude = c("AK", "HI"),
                  values = "ranking", color = "black") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(name = "Ranking", low = "red", mid = "white", 
                       high = "green") + 
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

which gives this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update** With `usmap >= 0.7.0` the issue is no longer reproducible as data objects are now returned as simple features.

```r
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

# Merge state polygons with ranking data
state_map_rankings <- merge(state_map, state_rankings,
  by.x = "abbr", by.y = "state"
)

# Create the ggplot2 map
ggplot(state_map_rankings, aes(
  fill = ranking
)) +
  geom_sf(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "red", mid = "white",
    high = "green", midpoint = 0
  ) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

**Original answer**

The issue is that the points which define the polygon get connected in the order as in your data. However, the `merge` will reorder you data and the rows are no longer in the right order  To fix that reorder or rearrange your data by both `group` and `order`:

```r
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)

# Merge state polygons with ranking data
state_map_rankings <- merge(state_map, state_rankings, by.x = "abbr", by.y = "state")
state_map_rankings <- state_map_rankings[order(state_map_rankings$group, state_map_rankings$order), ]

# Create the ggplot2 map
ggplot(state_map_rankings, aes(
  x = x, y = y,
  group = group, fill = ranking
)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "red", mid = "white",
    high = "green", midpoint = 0
  ) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)
state_rankings <- data.frame(
  state = c(
    "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT",
    "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN",
    "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA",
    "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV",
    "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH",
    "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN",
    "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"
  ),
  ranking = runif(50, min = -2, max = 2)
)

# Get state polygons
state_map <- usmap::us_map(regions = "states")
```

Comment: This is a better answer to the original question. However I would note that the red green color scheme is not colorblind-friendly. I would recommend using colors chosen from the Okabe-Ito colors that can be accessed using `palette.colors()`